# NetBeans fails to execute a Perl script when compiling C++ project

Tags: c++, perl, netbeans, compilation, mingw

I installed [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) 6.9.1 with C++ support. I also installed [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW).

When I create a C++ project and run it, I get this:

[image: Compile Error Screenshot]

I checked the C++ configuration in NetBeans (looks good):

[image: NetBeans C++ Configuration]

Perl is installed on my PC under `C:\perl`.

I tried reinstalling NetBeans, and I tried removing NetBeans and Perl and then reinstalled NetBeans. It didn't work (`perl` is not recognized as internal command).

Otherwise, I have to work with [Dev-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C++) :( (I like the NetBeans functionality better:) )

Comment: Next time, copy and paste the error message here rather than taking screenshots.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be using MinGW's `make`?

Comment: yes i should have, that was the mistake :)

Comment: aren't screenshots more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to change the path to msys in NetBeans, because I installed some package to develop in Symbian.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you installed NetBeans in a directory with a space in the name: "Program Files". Many Unix tools do not work properly with paths containing spaces. Try to reinstall NetBeans in a directory that does not contain spaces.

Comment: apperantly i had to change the path to msys in netbeans  because i installed some package to develop in symbian